# Setting up Magento 2 for multiple stores

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, multistore, url, stores

After creating a **second website** on my Magento admin (setting up the store, storeview, base url etc.) I **can't reach the newly created store**. Whenever I go try the url I want website to use I just get **redirected to my main store**.
I also configured the DNS settings correctly (I think).

Example:
Main Store: `main.store.eu`
Second store: `store.second.eu`

Whenever I use `store.second.eu` it redirects me to `main.store.eu`
I've been looking into the `magento2/index.php` file and `magento2/nginx.config` but the explanations aren't totally clear, talk about M1 or talk about an Apache server...

Can somebody please help :)

Answer (score 1):

You should add this to your .htaccess files inside `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>`

```
SetEnvIf Host .*store.second.eu.* MAGE_RUN_CODE=CODE
SetEnvIf Host .*store.second.eu.* MAGE_RUN_TYPE=website
```

where you should replace MAGE_RUN_CODE with your website code.

More info on [devdocs](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/config-guide/multi-site/ms_over.html)

Comment: Unfortunately my hosting service doesn't work this way... I'm working with a  [Hypernode](https://hypernode.com/). [Here](https://support.hypernode.com/knowledgebase/multistore-in-subfolders-setup-in-nginx/) they give a short explanation on multisture but it's not clear at all to me what I should do.

Comment: You can't edit the .htaccess file in your magento root dir?

Comment: I can edit the file but it's not going to help if I can follow my hosting service's knowledge base.